# Shared Preferences between fragment and dialog

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, sharedpreferences

So, I'm trying to save a message that I believe should be saved in shared preferences so that I can edit it later and share it with other fragments. I have a fragment with a button that opens a dialog that includes an edit box and I want to save whatever is written into the edit box as a string that can be used later in another activity. The problem is, that I can't bring the message back once it has been set, so I can't edit the message at all.

This is the button click which sets up the dialog to put in the options, including a radio group and the edit text box:

```
case R.id.settings_my_health_alert_settings:
            //Set Up Dialog
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.myhealth_alert_settings);
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.setTitle(R.string.health_alert_dialogue_title);

            // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
            RadioButton1 = (RadioButton)dialog.findViewById(R.id.intervalOnce);
            RadioButton2 = (RadioButton)dialog.findViewById(R.id.interval5min);
            RadioButton3 = (RadioButton)dialog.findViewById(R.id.interval10min);
            radioGroup = (RadioGroup) dialog.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);

            Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ok_btn);
            Button cancelButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
            // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
            dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(RadioButton1.isChecked()) {
                        AlertService.isOnce = true;
                    }
                    if(RadioButton2.isChecked()){
                        AlertService.isOnce = false;
                        intervalTime = 5;
                    }
                    if(RadioButton3.isChecked()){
                        AlertService.isOnce = false;
                        intervalTime = 10;
                    }

                    SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor = prefs.edit();
                    mEditor.putString("message", msg);
                    mEditor.apply();

                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
```

This is the part of the OnCreateView which seems like the place to put it if I want to get the string from shared preferences to show when the dialog is opened every time. But I keep getting a null pointer.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("my_health_settings", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor = prefs.edit();
                    mEditor.putString("message", msg);
                    mEditor.commit();

                    String edt = prefs.getString("message", "");
                    if (edt == null) {
                        editT = "Emergency at: " +MyHealthFragment.address;
                        editTextBox.setText(editT);
                    } else {
                        editTextBox.setText(edt);
                    }
```

Remember that the string in shared preferences needs to be accessible to another fragment as well.

I can't figure out the best logic for this - put it in onCreateView? or onClick? or something completely different that I'm missing and then also, if nothing is set in the edit box, have a standard back up message... any help would be great. I hope it makes sense.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:  This is the Logcat that I get:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.nesscorporation.android.sibext.fragment.settings.dropdown.MyHealthSettingsFragment.<init>(MyHealthSettingsFragment.java:58)
        at com.nesscorporation.android.sibext.fragment.settings.dropdown.MyHealthSettingsFragment.getInstance(MyHealthSettingsFragment.java:41)
```

I don't actually have an alert settings fragment, just the xml for the dialog.

Here's the WHOLE fragment (with some things that I'm trying out):

```
public class MyHealthSettingsFragment extends BaseSettingsFragment implements View.OnClickListener {

public static MyHealthSettingsFragment getInstance(){
    return new MyHealthSettingsFragment();
}

private static final String TAG = "Koz";

private View pillRemindTitle;
private View contactsTitle;
private View alertSettings;
public static String message = "";
public static int intervalTime = 5;
public RadioButton RadioButton1;
public RadioButton RadioButton2;
public RadioButton RadioButton3;
private RadioGroup radioGroup;
private EditText editTextBox;
private String editT;
private String msg;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = View.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.settings_my_health_fragment, null);

    pillRemindTitle = v.findViewById(R.id.settings_my_health_pills_rem);
    contactsTitle = v.findViewById(R.id.settings_my_health_contact_title);
    alertSettings = v.findViewById(R.id.settings_my_health_alert_settings);
    editTextBox = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.edit_message);

    pillRemindTitle.setOnClickListener(this);
    contactsTitle.setOnClickListener(this);
    alertSettings.setOnClickListener(this);

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){

        case R.id.settings_my_health_pills_rem:
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), PillRemindersActivity.class));
            break;
        case R.id.settings_my_health_contact_title:
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), ContactsActivity.class));
            break;
        case R.id.settings_my_health_alert_settings:
            //Set Up Dialog
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());

            //final String msg = message.getText().toString();
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.myhealth_alert_settings);
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.setTitle(R.string.health_alert_dialogue_title);
            ((TextView)dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.title)).setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),"walkway_expand_bold.ttf"));

            // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
            RadioButton1 = (RadioButton)dialog.findViewById(R.id.intervalOnce);
            RadioButton2 = (RadioButton)dialog.findViewById(R.id.interval5min);
            RadioButton3 = (RadioButton)dialog.findViewById(R.id.interval10min);
            radioGroup = (RadioGroup) dialog.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);

            Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ok_btn);
            Button cancelButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
            // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
            dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(RadioButton1.isChecked()) {
                        AlertService.isOnce = true;
                    }
                    if(RadioButton2.isChecked()){
                        AlertService.isOnce = false;
                        intervalTime = 5;
                    }
                    if(RadioButton3.isChecked()){
                        AlertService.isOnce = false;
                        intervalTime = 10;
                    }

                    SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("my_health_settings", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor = prefs.edit();
                    mEditor.putString("message", msg);
                    mEditor.commit();

                    String edt = prefs.getString("message", "");
                    //Log.d(TAG, edt);
                    if (edt == null) {
                        //editT = "Emergency at: " +MyHealthFragment.address;
                        //editTextBox.setText(editT);
                        Log.d(TAG, "null");
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, edt);
                        //editTextBox.setText(edt);
                    }

                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            dialog.show();
            //SMS or MMS: radio group sms or mms (with image of map)
            break;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get any text written into the dialog edit box to come up every time in the dialog edit box so that it can be edited as per the users wish.

Comment: where is your logcat? post it.

Comment: write value of prefs  in settings_my_health_alert_settings?

Comment: Please post some more code of your fragment where you are getting value from your preference.

Comment: Posted the whole fragment...

Answer (score 0):

After adding message in your `SharedPreference` you have to commit it.
Try as below in your activity to add value in preference:

```
       SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("my_health_settings", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor = prefs.edit();
        mEditor.putString("message", msg);
        mEditor.commit();
```

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that, but it doesn't seem to work, or change the issue. I've also edited the question again.